# insert value from sharepoint list to SQL table

Tags: list, sql

I have list with approx 20000 items, and want to push that into sql table. Can anyone help me with c# code. Thanks

Comment: Please share your work. What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to export the SharePoint list in excel and then import that data into SQL table using SQL management studio,

But still if you want to go by C#, then you can get all list items using below code and then insert into SQL table

```
using ( SPSite site = new SPSite ("http://moss/sites/yousitename"))
{

  SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb();
  SPList target = myWeb.Lists["YourListName"];
  SPListItems items = list.Items;
  myWeb.Dispose();
 }
```

for more information check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d61926a-9a18-422f-a34a-dda3e8b3eab1/how-to-export-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-to-a-sql-database